# Why am I exceeding max pool for database connections in .net using ajax calls?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ajax

I am building a web page for a project in .net that displays a basketball tournament bracket. Each team has a button next to their name that when clicked advances them in the bracket and the team they played moves to a loser bracket (it's for double elimination). You can drag the bracket and zoom so I decided to use ajax calls to update winners and losers and then display the results without posting back, refreshing page, and losing zoom / drag positions.

While selecting winners for a 64 team bracket, the ajax calls work pretty quickly and return results right away. After I get part way through though, the call takes several seconds and then eventually returns an error, which means the update wasn't made and that I'm not getting any return bracket results. When I open another page of the site in another tab, it takes awhile to load and eventually I get an error that indicates I'm not able to query the database.

This is the code / flow of the process:

-When the winning team is clicked, this is called:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Handlers/TestHandler.ashx',    
        data: { 'tournamentID': tournamentID },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            switch (response[0].toString().toUpperCase()) {
                case "SUCCESS":
                    PopulateBracket(response);
                    break;                    
                default:
                    alert('Error setting winner.');
                    break;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error setting winner.');
        }
    });
```

-The results from the call are brought back as json and populate the bracket with updated results.

-Inside the handler, I create a new instance of a data access layer class I have created to make querying my db a bit easier.

-I then perform the necessary logic to determine where teams will go.

-I attempt to perform an insert record for the winner and loser as well as query for the bracket results in one query. If that fails, I perform an update to the record and return bracket results (if someone is updating a match, I figured it would be easiest to attempt an insert and on fail perform an update instead of doing a select on the match to see if rows exist to know whether to do an insert or an update).

-This is a simplified version of how the handler works (I tack on "SUCCESS" or "ERROR" to the returned json so that I know if there were issues or not - see the switch statement in the ajax call above):

```
DAL dl = new DAL();
DataTable dt = dl.GetDataTable("INSERT; SELECT;");
if dt is null or empty, dt = dl.GetDataTable("UPDATE; SELECT;");
context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dt))
```

-This is how the data access layer (DAL) works:

```
public class DAL
{
    String cnnStr;

    public DAL() 
    {
        cnnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public DataTable GetDataTable(String sql, ref String error)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {                            
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        error = e.Message;

                        if (debugMode)
                            Console.Write(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

So...from what I have read, I am closing my connections properly in my data access layer. I'm minimizing my database calls to only two per selection of a winner for a match. I'm waiting for an ajax call to finish before initiating another call (I have an un-closable loading popup appear while the call is being made that goes away once the call is finished - either successfully or not). The bracket also populates with the new results, which is another indicator that the call was successful.

Why is it that after filling out some of the bracket this is happening? If I go into the control panel of the hosting solution I'm using and restart the website and recycle app pool everything seems to work fine again after a minute.

Is it that somehow I'm reaching the max pool size for my database connection? Any ideas on how this might be happening?

**UPDATE:**

I didn't spend time researching the problem as I had a similar issue on a page that was attempting to refresh results every 30 seconds via a javascript timer and ajax call. Instead I created an alternative that works. It may not be the most elegant solution but it works.

Here it is:

-Place an update panel on the page.

-Place two hidden fields in the update panel. One for the data that will populate the bracket (let's say it's called 'HiddenBracketDataBox') and one for submission of the winner of a match (let's say it's called 'HiddenSubmissionBox').

-In the code behind file within Page_Load, I run some code that checks the HiddenSubmissionBox value. If valid (not blank, in the correct format, etc), then fire code to post the submission to the database. If HiddenSubmissionBox is empty, nothing fires. At the end of the function, I clear out the HiddenSubmissionBox field so there is no issue with attempts at resubmission.

-After this function I have a function that queries for the bracket data (important that this is after the submission code so I pick up the submission and get the most current data that includes the recent submission). This function returns data that I can then dump into the HiddenBracketDataBox field.

-In the $(document).ready(function () {}; section of my javascript, I call a function (let's say it's called 'PopulateData') to populate the bracket data by pulling in data from the HiddenBracketDataBox field, processing it, and placing it in the correct bracket positions.

-After calling PopulateData, I perform the following (this is to make sure that refreshing the update panel will populate the bracket):

```
try {    
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);        
} catch (e) {}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    PopulateData();
}
```

-And finally, the last piece of the puzzle is what happens on click of the winning team. For that I set the value of HiddenSubmissionBox to something that indicates what team is being submitted as winner and for what position in the bracket. This is what then gets picked up by the Page_Load code and posted to the db. After setting the HiddenSubmissionBox value, I then call

```
__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', 'REFRESH');
```

to cause the update panel to refresh, which then in turn calls the submission function and gets bracket results that get posted to the hidden field.

And that's it. Like I said, not the most elegant but it works. I went through and selected winners through a 32 team bracket twice over and never had a single problem. Before I could maybe get through one and little bit of a second at most. This solution lets .net handle the cleanup that is apparently missing as well as maintain the appearance of a page that doesn't refresh.

Good luck, we're all counting on you. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Are you sure you are not creating a race condition with multiple AJAX calls?  Can you do a console.log before your AJAX call, then F12 to see how the call is behaving.

Comment: @AndyPowell Thanks for your response. I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect no because as the ajax call would fire the success code to populate the bracket, it would populate the correct results (moving the winner and loser to the correct positions on the bracket). I wouldn't select the next winner on the bracket until the results from the previous call came back. The results would come back immediately right up until the last call that eventually locks the site (or the db as it were). Selecting a winner and making the ajax call would work for about 100 times before the issue occurs.

Comment: @AndyPowell Which would lead me to believe that for some reason there isn't proper release of db connections and they just pile up until the max pool is reached (should be 100 for me as I haven't changed any defaults). If I programmed the ajax call, the handler, and the data access layer correctly, I'm not sure what else can be done other than to somehow forcefully close connections after each call. That doesn't seem like a good option. I don't know if this can be managed or is a bug or what.

Comment: @AndyPowell Since the post I've been working on an alternative (which is why it took me so long to get back to you, for which I apologize).